# How to write Timestamp with Before Christ date in PostgreSQL via jdbc?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, timestamp

I've tried to write the date Before Christ in PostgreSQL with `PreparedStatement` and failed.
Are there any tricks to do this?

The field in Postgres is TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE.

When I tried to write it as a string via `Statement` like SQL `insert into public.tstest1(ts1) values('"2014-01-11 14:00:08.354 BC"')`  - it works. 
But I can't correctly retrieve it with common `ResultSet` - it loses the "BC" part and incorrectly shows days or year - in any case - it works in Anno Domini AD .

I checked with `SimpleDateFormat` that I got BC date in output after preparing `java.sql.Timestamp` with the year 2014 BC like `new Timestamp(-2014-1900+1, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01)`.

But can't achieve the same after writing to database.

```
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO public.tstest1(ts1) VALUES (?)");        

    Timestamp tsBC = new Timestamp(-2014-1900+1, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01, 01);
    Date dt1 = new Date(tsBC.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm z G");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(dt1));

    pstmt.setTimestamp(1, tsBC);
    pstmt.execute();

    pstmt.clearParameters();

    pstmt.setDate(1, dt1);
    pstmt.execute();

    pstmt.clearParameters();
    pstmt.setObject(1, dt1);
    pstmt.execute();

    pstmt.clearParameters();
    pstmt.setObject(1, tsBC);
    pstmt.execute();

    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have't shown us how do you retrieve and display `ts1` field. I have tried your example and it works well. I retrieve `ts1` field with `getString()` and it displays values like

```
"2014-03-04 05:06:07 BC"
```

When I retrieve it with `getTimestamp()` I retrieve the same value as I inserted and it with your `SimpleDateFormat` it is dispalyed as:

```
2014/03/04 05:06 CET p.n.e.
```

Where `p.n.e.` means BC in Polish (my locale).

I use PostgreSQL 9.3 and `postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar`

Comment: The solution was to move to the newest version 9.x jdbc driver. And i experienced the problem with the old one pg74.